# indicator-datetime problem

Tags: indicator

I am using ubuntu 10.04 and since a few days ago, I do not have the time on my panel any more. As I already found among answers to similar issues, it must be related to "indicator-datetime" but it seems that this application is obsolete. Does anyone know what I should exactly do get the time back?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: you can add a new panel and delete the previous one.. adding the time applet to the panel may also help u !

Comment: Do you still have the other indicators like messaging, session, etc?

Answer (score 0):

try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall indicator-datetime`

or `sudo apt-get install indicator-datetime`

logout and log in